# How to rotate my object with the light in opengl

Tags: opengl, graphics, rotation, lighting

In my code, I cannot set cordinate the lighting according to the object so I cannot with fixed my lighting on the object which moves. How can i move the light with the objects

I have an objet that is in the 0,0,-15 position and When I press the up down right left buttons , this object moving with the light which is lamb object. Yet, although I put the light(lamb object) 0,0,-15 position and give move_x and move_z cordinates as a position of light , the light is appeared in the different place and it is moving unlinked with my object. this is my code :

```
            glTranslatef(move_x,0,move_y);
            float l0_pos_temp[] = {move_x   ,-3, move_y  ,1} ;
            glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, l0_pos_temp ) ;
            glTranslatef(0,-3,0);
            Light();
        glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what you're asking for. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve in greater detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important thing to note, is that glLightfv() is affected by the current state of the modelview matrix. That is
calling glTranslatef(move_x,0,move_y), before setting the light position will translate the light by (move_x,0,move_y).

Perhaps you want:

```
        glTranslatef(move_x,0,move_y);
        float l0_pos_temp[] = {0.0f, -3.0f, -15.0f, 1.0f};
        glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, l0_pos_temp );
        glPopMatrix();
```